# Is it possible for a moderator to be auto-banned from reviewing in the queues?

Tags: support, review-audits, moderators, review-suspension, moderator-abilities

I haven't seen or heard of a mod that deserves to be banned from reviewing. This is just a what-if type of question.

I was just wondering if it's possible for a mod to be doing reviews in the queues, and say they fail enough audits, would they get automatically suspended from reviewing like normal users?

Do mods even get audits at all in the queues?

Has there ever been an SO mod that got suspended from reviewing while being a mod?

Comment: _"I was just wondering"_ Why? Does it actually concern you, what you'll meet when being elected as a moderator?

Comment: I think I've seen mods report failing review audits in could moments here on meta. On mobile now though so I don't feel like researching.

Comment: @AndrewMedico - Bill might hate me for posting this, but I still get a chuckle out of this one: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ow6Fc.png

Comment: @BradLarson That wouldn't be half as embarrassing if it had been *any other mod* who had deleted that post about a week before.

Comment: It wouldn't have been 1/10 as embarrassing, if not for that, @Bill!

Comment: This question is off-topic because it tries to determine if moderators are human.

Comment: @rene …and we clearly can't have people realizing the truth of the matter!

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Yes, we get presented with audits, and yes I've heard we can get banned. I recall someone experimenting with this once and it worked.

However, given that we can access the ban list and could remove ourselves from it, this doesn't have a lot of teeth.

Comment: I think said mod would be more worried about the (good-natured) scorn of their fellow mods, anyway! Screenshots are forever... ;)

Comment: "I recall someone experimenting with this once and it worked." Yeah, "experimenting"...

Comment: How do you access the ban list if you are banned?

Comment: @TylerH Banned from conducting reviews, not banned from the site.

Comment: @TylerH: Actually, we can suspend and unsuspend ourselves - or other moderators - on a whim.

Comment: Unbanning yourself from the review blacklist is like a Congressman voting for his own raise.

Comment: @ChrisBaker Which, at least in the U.S., is something of a myth. There's a Constitutional ban against a sitting Congress voting a salary change for itself (27th Amendment.) They can, however, vote a salary change for the subsequent Congress (of which they may or may not be a part.) In 1989, a law was passed that set Congress' annual pay raises to the minimum of either the pay increase for GS federal employees or the year-over-year increase in the Employment Cost Index. However, since 2009, Congress has voted to forego those raises entirely.