# Is there a reputational threshold for becoming a "trusted reviewer" - no audits?

Tags: support, review-audits

As I was having a look at [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318090/bad-question-used-as-test-in-review-queue-gives-me-review-ban?cb=1), which also has happened to me, the thought occurred to me that there might be a point in the privilege hierarchy when a reviewer is no longer audited.  Or at least, when audit failures don't automatically trigger a ban.  Is this the case?

Comment: AFAIK, the only "threshold" is that the more audits you pass, the less you see. You will ALWAYS see audits.

Comment: There are several 20K+ users who have been banned from review over 40 times for approving spam and repeatedly failing suggested edit audits. Unfortunately, some of the worst review abusers are high-rep users chasing badges.

Comment: @BradLarson The supply of review-related badges runs out rather quickly, so I don't think chasing badges is a good explanation.

Comment: @BradLarson should we maybe do something about that?

Comment: The limit, if there is one, is bigger than John Skeet's current score.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

No, even now with 200k reputation, I still see audits. I saw them when I was a site moderator as well, so even that level of trust isn't enough. ;)

Also, audit failures will *always* trigger a ban if you fail enough of them in a short enough period of time. Don't think of it as a punishment. It's just the system telling you that you need to slow down and pay attention to what you're doing (after taking a short break from reviewing).

Comment: That begs a question - what did the system do to you if (when?) you failed them?

Comment: @theMayer It did the same to me as to anyone else. It banned me from doing reviews for a while.

Comment: I've gotten myself banned too. *No one* is immune. There is a threshold beyond which you see *fewer* audits though, based on the % of audits you've passed.

Comment: Am I the only person who feels this seems arbitrary and capricious?

Comment: @TheMayer The intent of audits is to make sure people don't "robo-review". Since robo-reviewing can come from growing complacent... I think it makes a LOT of sense to always check.... just less often

Comment: @Patrice- good point

Comment: But mods can un- review ban themselves, right ? I think I read about a mod experimenting with this, somewhere.

Comment: @JonasCz or as BoltClock put it, "experimenting". http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284136/

Comment: @theMayer I agree with the need for audits for everyone, but I vehemently disagree with two facets (actually both sides of the same coin): the audits are chosen mechanically, and there is no way to appeal a bad audit failure. I've been banned for failing bad audits, and have stopped reviewing until an appeal mechanism is instituted.

Comment: @JimGarrison: I suppose you mean an automated appeal mechanism, since the current one is simply posting about the bad audit on meta?

Comment: I think the failed audit screen could do with a lot more honesty. It should make clear that it is automated and might actually be a bad call. If I were a robo-reviewer then I'd just be sitting there mashing the 'OK' button anyway.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261032/is-it-possible-to-review-a-review-audit#comment49219_261036

Comment: I have a question. System shows you when you passed audit. Will it show you if you've failed?

Comment: @IgorYavych Yes, it also tells you if you failed. Quite clearly, as a matter of fact...

Comment: @CindyMeister thanks, haven't seen that one yet so I was wondering.